# Is there a minimum width that Bootstrap 3 supports?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

When I shrink my browser window down width wise it seems around 420px is the lowest it will let me go.

I am referring to Bootstrap 3 with no custom media queries.

Can you design responsive Bootstrap 3 for screen widths of 280px without requiring custom media queries?

Thanks.

Comment: I am not an expert in bootstrap 3 but I remember that it is Mobile First. So, what you are doing doesn't sound like a good idea to start with. You should be querying from Mobile to Larger Screens, not vice versa.

Comment: Desktop browsers don't get as small as the smallest device, which as of now, is 240px wide by 320px (Android). 

Bootstrap is fluid and responsive. You can use it to make sites for any device width since it's fluid. If you are not familiar with either fluid design and responsive mobile first CSS, I suggest learning that first

Answer (score 0):

At screen widths below 360px, [top-level `.col-xs-1` Bootstrap grid columns start to wrap](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/10513) (even though conceptually, they're supposed to never wrap). See also https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/13221

The problem can be mostly avoided by not using `col-xs-1` on very small screens. Or by using custom media queries.

Answer (score 0):

Read about the visible-xs,visible-md etc...

You will first understand the visible class of bootstrap which you find here...

[responsiveness in twitterbootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities)